# Where can I find a decent HTML Table visual editor?

Tags: html, html-table, ide, editor

Adobe Dreamweaver has nice HTML table visual editor, which is great* for quickly editing large tabular data, for example adding deleting rows without having to worry about properly nested tr and td.

Are there any other IDE's or stand alone apps that provide a visual editor for html tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/bgkittrell/yui-rte-tables